# `r`/`rlang`/`dplyr`: How to render `sym` resilient to `NULL`?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Edited in response to @akrun's insight:

This works:

```
require("magrittr")
requireNamespace("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(a = 1:5)

b_column <- c_column <- "a"
df %>% dplyr::mutate(
    b = !!dplyr::sym(b_column),
    c = !!dplyr::sym(c_column))
```

But when any one of the `*_column`s is `NULL` it doesn't:

```
c_column <- NULL
df %>% dplyr::mutate(
    b = !!dplyr::sym(b_column),
    c = !!dplyr::sym(c_column))
```

The resulting error is:

```
Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How would I make the call to ANY of the en`sym`boled `*_column` variables resilient to it being `NULL`?

Comment: `NULL` is not a string and column names can't be `NULL`

Comment: Well ok, but when matching arguments it's rather common to have a potential string default to NULL ...

Comment: Do you need `if(!is.null(c)) df %>% dplyr::mutate(b = !!dplyr::sym(c))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to check for `NULL` case, use an `if` condition

```
df1 <- if(!is.null(c)) {
       df %>%
          dplyr::mutate(b = !!dplyr::sym(c))
         } else df
```

---

With multiple columns, an option is `map`

```
library(purrr)
b_column <- c_column <- "a"
map2_dfc(list(b_column, c_column), c("b", "c"), ~ 
    if(!is.null(.x)) df %>% 
               transmute(!! .y := !! sym(.x))) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
#  a b c
#1 1 1 1
#2 2 2 2
#3 3 3 3
#4 4 4 4
#5 5 5 5
```

If one of them is `NULL`

```
c_column <- NULL
map2_dfc(list(b_column, c_column), c("b", "c"), ~  
         if(!is.null(.x)) df %>%
                     transmute(!! .y := !! sym(.x))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
#  a b
#1 1 1
#2 2 2
#3 3 3
#4 4 4
#5 5 5
```

---

Another option is `mutate` with `across`, but make sure that we need to `rename` only the columns that are not NULL

```
nm1 <- c("b", "c")
i1 <-  !map_lgl(list(b_column, c_column), is.null)
nm2 <- nm1[i1]
df %>% 
   mutate(across(all_of(c(b_column, c_column)), ~ .)) %>% 
   rename_at(vars(everything()), ~ nm2) %>% 
   bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: @balin I am assuming that you want to return the original dataset when the value for `c` is `NULL`

Comment: This indeed close to the use case. But see my edits above ...

Comment: @balin Can you check the updated solution